# Does the gigabyte ex58 ud4p board come with built in wireless?

Tags: wireless-networking, motherboard

Does the gigabyte ex58 ud4p board come with built in wireless?

I find it strange the guy at the store didn't try and sell me one.

So is it built in?

Answer (score 2):

Choose a good **PCI** Adapter.

- Avoid Adapters that are **not PCI** (like USB, Bluetooth) if you want good performance
- Try to match the Adapter with your Access-Point/Router hardware

  - Select the two together if you do not already have the AP
- Check [which wireless you want](http://compnetworking.about.com/cs/wireless80211/a/aa80211standard.htm)

  - If you have the AP already, that will bias your decision for the Adapter wireless

Answer (score 1):

No, all it has is that gigabit ethernet.
http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/Products/Motherboard/Products_Overview.aspx?ProductID=2986

If you want wireless, you'll have to install a wireless NIC, e.g.:

[image: w1reles5 n3tw0rk adapt3r]